# Binding iOS Static Library to Xamarin.iOS and using the dll

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, static-libraries, xamarin

I am able to successfully create dll file for my `Objective-C` static library. But when I am try to reference that dll from `Xamarin.iOS` application and compiling, it is giving me lot of error like...

> Error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: _AudioFileClose. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in. (MT5210)
>
> Error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: std::ios_base::Init::Init(). Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in. (MT5210)
>
> Error MT5202: Native linking failed. Please review the build log. (MT5202)

---

After this, I tried to link my .a library using Addtional mtouch Arguments. After adding those arguments, I am getting the new error.

> Could not parse the command line arguments: Cannot bundle unregistered option '-o'.

Could someone please help me in resolving this issues.

Comment: is this c++ ? if so, there's a special flag to pass

Comment: I Added is IsCxx = ture in Linkwith and in Additional mtouch Arguments I metioned -cxx -gcc_flags . But I am unable to resolve that problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally figured out the error!!

```
    [assembly: LinkWith (..., IsCxx = true, Frameworks = "CoreAudio AudioToolbox", LinkerFlags = "-lstdc++ -lz" )]
```

In iOS Binding Projet

Options > Build > Compiler > Addition Arguments

```
    -cxx -gcc_flags "-stdlib=libstdc++ -L${ProjectDir} -lMylibrary -force_load ${ProjectDir}/libMylibrary.a”
```

In my demo application

Options > iOS Buidl > Addtional mtouch Arguments

```
    --gcc_flags="-stdlib=libstdc++"
```

By giving the proper flags in all the places it resolved my issue.

Comment: FYI, I had a similar problem and I believe only the LinkerFlags/IsCxx and the -gcc_flags bits are required - the middle one didn't matter for me. (ForceLoad goes in the linkwith.cs)

Answer (score 7):

As Stephane mentioned, there's a IsCxx property on the LinkWithAttribute that you can set to specify that the .a library is a c++ library. That'll solve the `std::ios_base::Init::Init()` error.

To solve the `undefined symbol: _AudioFileClose` error, you might try adding the CoreAudio or perhaps AudioToolbox framework to the list of frameworks to link against:

```
[assembly: LinkWith (..., IsCxx = true, Frameworks = "CoreAudio AudioToolbox")]
```

Hopefully even if that doesn't quite work, it'll get you headed in the right direction.

Comment: Hi Added IsCxx=true in LinkWith But I am still getting : Native linking failed, undefined symbol: std::ios_base::Init::Init(). Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.

Comment: The AudioFileClose error was resolved by adding Frameworks in LinkWith file.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem installing the new version of Xcode. (now 7.1)
The error is misleading but now it works!